# Не получается прочитать свойство node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

В скрипте есть объект:

```js
user_ = {
  _id: 5fe5e5cf8c33b4183c5aa709,
  profile: { name: 'a', descr: 'b' },
  techProfile: { time: '1608902095352' }
}
```

По абсолютно непонятной мне причине я могу прочитать свойство `profile`, но не могу прочитать `techProfile`.

Выглядит это как-то так:

```
console.log(user_) // => { _id: 5fe5e5cf8c33b4183c5aa709, profile: { name: 'a', descr: 'b' }, techProfile: { time: '1608902095352' } }
console.log(user_.profile) // => { name: 'a', descr: 'b' }
console.log(user_.techProfile) // => undefined
```

При этом в браузерной среде все прекрасно работает.

Код исполняется в роуте:

```js
router.get('/get/:id',
    cors(corsOptions),
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.find({
                'id': req.params.id
            }, {
                "profile": 1,
                "techProfile": 1
            });
            const user_ = user[0];

            const profile = user_.profile;
            const techProfile = user_.techProfile;

            console.log(user_)

            const postedNews = await News.find({
                "author.id": req.params.id
            }, {
                "id": 1
            });

            profile.postedNews = postedNews.length;

            console.log(user_.techProfile)

            return res.status(200).json({
                profile
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.stack)
            return res.status(500).json({
                msg: config.get("msgs.statuses.500err")
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Как прочитать `techProfile`?

Comment: @Дмытрык, 1) Есть 2) Да

Comment: Я пока сам тестировал переписал поле в бд и в коде. Не помогло, пойду попробую ещё раз

Comment: @Дмытрык, но это достаточно странно, учитывая, что получаю я их одновременно и через await

Comment: @Дмытрык, я разобрался, когда я добавлял поле `techInfo`, я забыл добавить его в модель